# ALAssetRepresentation fullResolutionImage with large image?

Tags: ios, large-files, alassetslibrary

when photo size over 10M (ex: by pano), use [ALAssetRepresentation fullResolutionImage] will be over memory and crash.but fullScreenImage  limit by screen.
There are other ways to solve ? i want get large picture from album.

Comment: You are use fullScreenImage from ALAssetRepresentation.

Comment: Your image is big, change the thumbnail image using `ALAsset` reduced the size and you get the original image.